# Including header file to each .h file in project by command options in Visual C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, include, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have a quite huge project.

And each of my .h file needs to include one specific file, `errorHandler.h`. But I don't want to do it by putting:

```
#include "errorHanlder.h"
```

at the top of each of them.

Moreover, in future I will have few implementations of `errorHandler`, so I would like to be able to change (fast) `errorHandler.h` to `winErrorHandler.h`, `winErrorHandler2.h`, `unixErrorHandler.h` or something like that.

**Is there a possibility to include that file *automatically* using the Visual C++ 2012?**

I mean something like *automatic* defines:

`Project->Configuration Preporties->C/C++->Preprocessor->PreprocessorDefinitions`
When I write there e.g. `myDef` it's the same result as putting `#define myDef` in each file of project.

So in the same way, I would like to put somehow `#include "errorHandler.h"` in each file of project.

Comment: You need a prefix file for your project. I don't remember where you set it in Visual Studio, but maybe knowing the name will help

Comment: You could try using ForcedInclude in the c++, advanced section of the project config.  From what I remember though it only forces the include for c/cpp files that are processed.  Since it would be first then perhaps it meets your need because any header would be included after it.

Comment: @Retired Ninja worked like a charm! Can you make an answer from your comment so I can mark it? Project->Configuration Preporties->C/C++->Advanced->Force Include File. Anyway for now I try to include "../errorHandler.h" - for some files it's "../", for some "../../" etc. - is there possibility (other than adding direct path like "F:/libs/errorHandler.h" or setting additional headers folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to include that file automatically using the Visual C++ 2012?

You can use `/FI` to force an include of a file that's not included in the project's source files. I use it when porting libraries to Windows RT and Windows Phone. For example:

```
/FI SDKDDKVer.h /FI winapifamily.h
```

is effectively:

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
#include <winapifamily.h>
```

Below is a patch I have for OpenSSL that forces some Windows Phone and Windows RT includes.

There's a property page for the option. You can find it at `Project->Configuration Preporties->C/C++->Advanced->Force Include File` (thanks PolGraphic and Retired Ninja).

The list of options for `cl.exe` is available at [Compiler Options Listed Alphabetically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx). `/I` will allow you to specify a header path, like GCC's `-I`.

---

[image]

Comment: Project->Configuration Preporties->C/C++->Advanced->Force Include File (pointed in the comment by  Retired Ninja). Can you add it to your answer (so people from future will have complex solution ;P )?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the precompiled header feature then putting the common #include into stdafx.h will accomplish the same thing as putting it into every h file in the entire project. stdafx.h is processed before any other header.

Comment: It's kind of an option for some people (so vote up from me), but I don't use pre-compiled headers and don't want to be forced to use them just because of that.